# Jenkins Graphs on GitHub README.md

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins CI can make graphs of the build information, like checkstyle graphs. This is normally displayed in the build information on the jenkins CI server, but no one looks at that.

I would like to put the graphs in a more accessible place. I think it is a cool idea send an email with the graphs (linked below), but I was wondering if it is possible to display the graphs on GitHub in the README.md for the repository.

From the "Sending Build Trend Graph as email" link below, I know that the uri for the graph is something like this: `<img src="${PROJECT_URL}test/trend" />`

I can see the graph as an image but I believe, viewing that graph image is still behind an authentication, so it won't display in the README.md. How could I make this image available for an anonymous user, so it can be displayed in GitHub? or is there a better way of doing it?

For sending an email with jenkins graphs:
[Jenkins : Sending Build Trend Graph as email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595286/jenkins-sending-build-trend-graph-as-email)

Comment: It might be here somewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298036/jenkins-graphs-in-embedded-in-mail-or-as-attachment

Comment: Some more options: you can grant read persmissions to anonymous user for this job or you can laucn another webserver that will expose this image for public audience via redirecting.

Comment: It seems to only work with the overall configure being set to "read". Having the job at "read" doesn't seem to change the images view status.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to view the job anonymously with the read permission set.